# Ground State Entropy of a Ferromagnet and Antiferromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, entropy, ising-model

Consider the ground state of a 1D Ising model.

In the ferromagnetic case, if we are to have magnetisation along the z axis, then there is one possible microstate, with all spins aligned along z. Hence the entropy is $S=k_{B}\ln1=0$

In the antiferromagnetic case, we have no magnetisation and so there are two possible microstates. Hence the entropy is $S=k_{B}\ln2\neq0$.

Is this right? It seems to conflict the third law of thermodynamics...

Answer (score 2):

Both cases have two possible microstates. In the ferromagnetic case, you have to be aligned along the z-axis, but you can have all spins pointing either up or down.

You might have heard the third law expressed as "The entropy at $T=0$ is zero," but that's just not true. That's something people believed before the development of statistical mechanics, but it's usually not how the third law is stated anymore. Usually, people give the third law as: "It's impossible to cool to $T=0$ in finite time."